# React Native Bug when Assembling Release on Windows

Tags: android, react-native

When trying to assemble the release of my application in Windows, I get the following error:

> Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' property '$1' during up-to-date check.
>
> > Failed to create MD5 hash for file content.

Both:

> react-native run-android --variant=release

And:

> gradlew assembleRelease

Won't work, however, it does work when I build the debug version with just:

> react-native run-android

I've done some research and this seems to be a bug that only exists on Windows.  I've also seen suggestions like:

- Ensure NODE_ENV is not set to 'development'
- .gradle is in the same directory as the outputDir and is causing locking issues with Windows
- Try bundling the project manually with `--dev false` option (this doesn't give me an error but I don't know what to do after it's bundled)

The problem is only when assembling the release version and it seems to break when reading the google-services.json file each time but can't seem to find anything online that links the error to that file.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here and how I could fix it?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the /node_modules folder and run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

- Delete the .gradle folder from the `C:/Users/_username_/`
- Delete the node_modules and reinstall and run

Comment: I don't see how this is answering the question? It should likely be a comment on the question, rather than an answer to it.

Comment: Updated now, sorry for before!